# <br/> tag and \n not working when concatinating and putting in a react component state variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to take input values from text box and displays every comment in new line.

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.displayCmnts=this.displayCmnts.bind(this);
            this.updateCmnts=this.updateCmnts.bind(this);
            this.state={
                 comments:'',
                 cmntCount:0,
                 prevCm:''
            }
        }
    render(){
            let c=(this.state.prevCm)
            return (
                   <div className="App">
                    <h3>enter comments</h3>
                    <input type="text" id="txt-cmnt" vlaue={this.state.comments} onChange= 
                    {this.updateCmnts} placeholder="enter"/>
                    <br/>
                    <button onClick={this.displayCmnts}>submit</button> 
                    <br/>
                    {c+<br/>}
                    </div>
                    );
             }
    updateCmnts(e){
            this.setState({comments:e.target.value});
        }
    displayCmnts(){
            this.setState({cmntCount:1});
            this.setState({comments:this.state.comments});
            var c=this.state.comments+"\n";
            this.setState({prevCm:this.state.prevCm+c});
}
```

when do this it  {c+
} outputs my-input-comments [object object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you change the code to `{c}<br/>` it should work

Comment: if  i add some other code below {c}<br/> then that code output would be in next line but text box input appear on the same line.

Comment: Is this the style you're going for? https://codepen.io/HuntingHawk/pen/RwNNaBZ If so, I recommend just wrapping {c} in a div tag so it sits at block level and then you wouldn't have to worry about breaks

Comment: it does not work as i am updating c every time with new input on submit button click

Comment: how about turning state.prevCm into an array and hold each comment as an array element. Then you can just ouput the comments calling map() on the array, e.g.: this.state.prevCm.map(function(cm) { return <div>{cm}</div>  })

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I would suggest making c an array of comments (strings) instead, then iterating over that array. Something like {c.map(s => {s}<br/>)} or {c.map(s => <div>{s}</div>)}, etc.